# Nanosecond plots using highstockJS

Tags: javascript, performance, time, highcharts

I'm trying to plot oscilloscope time traces using highcharts/highstock. The problem is highstock only takes the xAxis as date values. I can't figure out how to force it to only use seconds (because then I could just change the label to nanoseconds).

Highcharts on the other hand can plot anything really but doesnt have the advanced data grouping features that I need to plot these long (and sometimes concatenated - i.e. SUPER long) time traces.

I could go server side with it but I don't think anything beats highcharts in terms of usability and flexibility.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Would it be enough to display nanosecond precision in the tooltips, or do you need the axis labels themselves to have such a high precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider to modify labels, by formatter ?

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.dateFormat()